# Enumerable::each_with_index now optionally takes a arguments in Ruby 1.9. What significance and/or what is a use case for that?

Tags: ruby, enumerable, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8.7

In Ruby 1.8.7 and prior, `Enumerable::each_with_index` did not accept any arguments. In Ruby 1.9, it will accept an arbitrary number of arguments. [Documentation/code](http://railsapi.com/doc/ruby-v1.9.2/classes/Enumerable.html#M000879) shows that it simply passes those arguments along to `::each`. With the built in and standard library Enumerables, I believe passing an argument will yield an error, since the Enumerable's `::each` method isn't expecting parameters.

So I would guess this is only useful in creating your own Enumerable in which you do create an `::each` method that accepts arguments. What is an example where this would be useful?

Are there any other non-obvious consequences of this change?

Answer (score 2):

I went through some gems code and found almost no uses of that feature. One that it does, `spreadsheet`:

```
def each skip=dimensions[0], &block
  skip.upto(dimensions[1] - 1) do |idx|
    block.call row(idx)
  end
end
```

I don't really see that as an important change: `#each` is the base method for classes that mix-in module Enumerable, and methods added (map, select, ...) do not accept arguments.

Comment: `each_with_object` accepts arguments. Hope I'm not being too argumentative!

Comment: @Andrew, but each_with_object is an inject in disguise, so it's only natural you need an argument. I must admit, though, that I am not really sure about all this each thing, whether allowing arguments to each is important (or will be important) or just a minor detail. For my taste, in any case, each -being the base iterator- should accept no arguments.

Comment: One difference between `reduce` and `each_with_object` is that only the latter returns an enumerator when no block is given. Isn't that a significant difference?